# Search alike in EF database

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, model

I have got a login screen which gets `UserName` and `Password`, with the model `Users`. 
What I am trying to do is to find the user in my database, but I don't have any ID that can reference to which user I need. 
 
How can I use SqlQuery() to select the user I want which will be alike to the user entered in the login page ?

Example:
Let's say this is the DataBase

```
ID    UserName    Password    Name    Email    Address    RoleID
1     Locali      12563       Findme  a@b.com  asd 99     5
2     FindMe      f452        asd     B@a.com  das 99     5
```

And the login Page `User` object get: 
UserName: `FindMe` 
Password: `f452`

How can I search for something alike the login data and then retrieve all the missing data to the object ? 
**I have to do it with SQL**

Comment: Just curious, why SQL?

Comment: I am doing this for a school project and one of the demands is to use SQL and not all the new techie things

Comment: Wait, this is an "EF" as in, Entity Framework database, but your assignment is to not use Entity Framework?

Comment: Basically I can use everything, but I have to include SQL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [sql-injection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) proof way:

```
using (var ctx = new DbContext())
{
    var parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@UserName", "FindMe"));
    var parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@Password", "f452"));

    var user = ctx.Users.SqlQuery("Select * from Users where UserName = @UserName and Password = @Password", parameter1, parameter2)
                        .FirstOrDefault<Users>();
}
```

EF will retrieve all columns from the database and materialize them as object properties.

Comment: I can't use `FirstOrDefault<Users>()` I only got `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` but it's not helping.

Comment: To use `FirstOrDefault<>` add `using System.Linq;`